# launchsettings.json, appsettings.json, web.config

Tags: asp.net-core, octopus-deploy

I have a couple of confusions:

1. I published an ASP.NET Core project and I do not see launchsettings.json in bin\Release\PublishOutput. If I use Octopus, how do I configure attributes based on server type?
2. Is it possible to move launchsettings.json to the root folder instead of under properties?
3. If I want to use only one json like appsettings.json, can I merge both in the root folder?
4. Can web.config be used instead of launchsettings.json, and how?

Comment: `launchSettings.json` is only for Visual Studio. Other than that, it's not clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: In general, it is discouraged on Stack Overflow to put more that one question in one post, With your future questions please follow this guideline :)

Comment: @Chirs Pratt, I recently hosted asp core app on linux box and when I change the values of this launchSettings.json file of key applicationUrl, and hit dotnet run, hosting is configured to this value. So I think this file has its effects on dotnet run command also. If so, is this file read on CreateDefaultBuilder() method in Program.cs ?

Comment: When an app is launched with dotnet run:
launchSettings.json is read if available. environmentVariables settings in launchSettings.json override environment variables.

Answer (score 48):

Answers to your questions:

1. As Chris Pratt mentioned in comment, `launchSettings.json` is only used by Visual Studio. You can use [Octopus variables](https://octopus.com/docs/deploying-applications/variables) in Octopus.
2. Don't need `launchSettings.json` for publishing an app.
3. If there are settings that your application needs to use, please store them in `appsettings.json`. This will make deployments easier, since Octopus recognizes this file by default.
4. It depends on your requirements. `web.config` is used by IIS, not by your .NET Core application directly, hence IIS limitations to what you can configure might be applied.

Hints.

- If you have some environment specific variables, you can store them in environment specific `appsettings.json`, e.g. `appsettings.Release.json`.
- You can leave placeholders for Octopus variable substitution in your `appsettings.json` file, especially in environment specific one, e.g. `appsettings.Release.json` may contain a config value like "#{ConnectionString}" and during deployment Octopus would substitute this placeholder with the actual value from Octopus variables.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Net Core does not have web.config, so how IIS deal with it, can IIS also read appsettings.json?

Comment: If you don't have `web.config` in your project, it will be created when you publish. If you have one, it will be transformed to have correct parameters when published. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis?tabs=aspnetcore2x
And IIS can't use `appsettings.json`, only your application can.

Comment: @newbeedeveloper IIS Express should have no idea what those settings are, and Visual Studio is the bridge, https://blog.lextudio.com/how-visual-studio-launches-iis-express-to-debug-asp-net-core-apps-d7fd3677e3c3

Comment: @Ignas if `launchsettings.json` is only for VS how can I configure `applicationurl` for each application I have on a linux server?

Comment: @OffirPe'er What do you use `applicationurl` in your applications for? Are all your applications different products, ie not just another instance of the same application?

Comment: @Ignas, it's the same application but with different environment, production, staging and development

Comment: @OffirPe'er It might depend on your server setup, however I think you could have `applicationurl` in `appsettings.json`, and have your CD tool, e.g. Octopus to provide the correct value for the `applicationurl` depending on the environment.

Comment: From my experience today launchSettings.json should just have the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT value e.g. Development and then you have a appsettings.Development.json file with your dev config values. Ignore setting anything else in the launchSettings.json as it just gets ruddy confusing

Comment: why does `dotnet watch run --launch-profile "someprofile in launchsettings.json" work` if 'launchSettings.json is only used by Visual Studio'?

Comment: During development my connection string is in app settings json file. When I deploy to iis should I move it to web.config?

Comment: If launchsettings json is meant for dev purpose only, then why does the documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-apache?view=aspnetcore-6.0#publish-and-copy-over-the-app ask us to modify the `launchSettings.json`?

Comment: this answer needs to made into a blog post